# Separate files for rsa encryption and decryption

Tags: python, rsa

So I am trying to make two programs, one to encode a message using rsa encryption, and one to decode it. In the encryption file I have:

```
import rsa


def generateKeys():
    (publicKey, privateKey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)
    with open('keys/publicKey.pem', 'wb') as p:
        p.write(publicKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))
    with open('keys/privateKey.pem', 'wb') as p:
        p.write(privateKey.save_pkcs1('PEM'))


def loadKeys():
    with open('keys/publicKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        publicKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    with open('keys/privateKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        privateKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    return privateKey, publicKey


def encrypt(message, key):
    return rsa.encrypt(message.encode('ascii'), key)


def sign(message, key):
    return rsa.sign(message.encode('ascii'), key, 'SHA-1')


#generateKeys()
privateKey, publicKey = loadKeys()
print(f"public key: {publicKey}, private key: {privateKey}")
encryptme = input('Write your message here:')
ciphertext = encrypt(encryptme, publicKey)
signature = sign(encryptme, privateKey)

print(str(ciphertext))
#print(signature)
```

and in the decryption file I have:

```
import rsa


def loadKeys():
    with open('keys/publicKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        publicKey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    with open('keys/privateKey.pem', 'rb') as p:
        privateKey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(p.read())
    return privateKey, publicKey


def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        print(ciphertext)
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('ascii')
    except:
        return False


def verify(message, signature, key):
    try:
        return rsa.verify(message, signature, key, ) == 'SHA-1'
    except:
        return False


privateKey, publicKey = loadKeys()

ciphertext = input("message to decipher: ")
print(ciphertext)
text = decrypt(ciphertext, privateKey)

if text:
    print(f'Message text: {text}')
else:
    print(f'Unable to decrypt the message.')
```

whenever I encode text and then paste it into the input of the decryption program, it returns cannot decode message. If anyone knows why this is, I would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: try utf-8 encode/decode

Comment: unfortunately, this still returns unable to decrypt

Comment: `(publicKey, privateKey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)` is it correct order?

Comment: Both the signature and the encryption byte strings.  I'm not really comfortable with your converting it into a string using str(), and then never actually converting it back into a byte array.  If I try `x = encrypt("hello", publicKey); decrypt(x, privateKey)` it all words fine.

Comment: Likewise, your verify has problems because your sign() code correctly converts message to bytes, but your verify doesn't.  And as usual, the signature is a byte string, so you cannot just blithely convert it to a string and back.

Comment: @FrankYellin for your previous comment using a variable is not what I want to do because I want two separate files, and I would rather not have to pass the variable, and for my verify function, I will fix that but first I want encryption and decryption to work.

Comment: I'd recommend a binary-to-text-encoding for the ciphertext, e.g. `ciphertext = base64.b64encode(encrypt(encryptme, publicKey)).decode('utf8')`. If you output `ciphertext` and then copy/paste this to `ciphertext = input()`, decryption works with `decrypted = decrypt(base64.b64decode(ciphertext), privateKey)`. Note, due to overhead, the raw ciphertext should be stored (not the Base64 encoded).

Comment: Thank you so much @Topaco this worked like a charm, now I just need to get the sign and verify working

Comment: now my sign and verify functions won't work, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Based on my original code, how should I edit it to make it work with separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The byte string `ciphertext` is converted to a character string by `str()` or at the latest by `input()`.

Example: The 2 byte string `b'\x11\xed'` is converted by `str()` or by `input()` into an 11 bytes character string like a UTF8 encoding reveals: `b"b'\\x11\\xed'"`.

This character string must be converted back to the original byte string before decryption, which does not happen (or happens incorrectly) in the posted implementation (s. also the comments).

The problem can be easily solved if the ciphertext is Base64 encoded. This string can then be passed to `input()` via copy/paste and Base64 decoded before decryption. If it is necessary to store the ciphertext, it is recommended to store the raw ciphertext because of the Base64 overhead.

The following code implements encryption and decryption using Base64 encoding/decoding:

```py
import rsa
import base64

def generateKeys():
    return rsa.newkeys(1024)

def encrypt(message, key):
    return rsa.encrypt(message.encode('ascii'), key)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    try:
        return rsa.decrypt(ciphertext, key).decode('ascii')
    except:
        return False

(publicKey, privateKey) = generateKeys()
encryptme = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

# Encryption
ciphertext = encrypt(encryptme, publicKey) # store raw ciphertext in file system 
ciphertextB64 = base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode('utf8')
print(ciphertextB64)
ciphertextB64Input = input("message to decipher: ") # Enter the ciphertext with copy/paste
decrypted = decrypt(base64.b64decode(ciphertextB64Input), privateKey)
print(decrypted)
```

The same applies to signing:

```py
def sign(message, key):
    return rsa.sign(message.encode('ascii'), key, 'SHA-1')

def verify(message, signature, key):
    try:
        return rsa.verify(message.encode('ascii'), signature, key) == 'SHA-1'
    except:
        return False

# Signing
signme = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
signature = sign(signme, privateKey) # store raw signature in file system
signatureB64 = base64.b64encode(signature).decode('utf8')
print(signatureB64)
signatureB64Input = input("signature to verify: ")
verified = verify(signme, base64.b64decode(signatureB64Input), publicKey)
print(verified)
```

Note that there is another bug here: in `rsa.verify()` `message` must be replaced by `message.encode('ascii')`.